# Does TFS (Team Foundation Server) have the users number limitation when installed on a local host?

Tags: tfs, numbers, server, private

The MS TFS is free for 5 users. 
I want to know if we install it on our private server, it still has the number of users limitation?

Comment: This question would be better asked on forums specific to TFS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking licensing questions.

Answer (score 2):

[TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38190) is free for 5 users on premises, whereas [Visual Studio Online](http://visualstudio.com) is free for 5 users in a Microsoft cloud hosted environment.